# how to get an element from mongodb and to be used in routing code

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We are developing an e-commerce project in that now the task is to show the order history of a particular user  now we have two collections one is User and other is Orders in that when the username in the user collection is matched to the user name in the order collection then it has to show the list

Here is my routing code

```
  router.get("/shop/orderhistory", function(req, res){
  async.parallel({
  categories: function(cb){
    Category.find({}, cb);
  },

  categories1:function(cb){
    Category.find({}, cb);
  },
   orderlists:function(cb){
      Userlist.find({},cb)
  },
  orders1:function(cb){
  Order.find({first_name:*******},cb)
  }
 }, function(err, results) {

     if (err) throw err;
      viewModel.categories1=results.categories1;
      viewModel.categories=results.categories;
      viewModel.orders1=results.orders1;
      res.render('shop/orderhistory',viewModel);
     });
   });
```

In the ABOVE code when first_name is the user name in the order collection 
Now my need is how can get the username in user table and to compare with the first_Name in the order table and to render the page

When i gave first_name:Harish an existed name in the order table then it will show the orders related to that name only like that when an user logged in the first_name to be compared with that username who logged in and to render the page

Comment: not understood what you want but you can try using JOINS.

Answer (score 0):

These two task that are **fetching users** and **fetching orders of these users** are dependent tasks. You cannot do async.parallel on them. They have to be in series. Use [async.waterfall](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall). So first a function will fetch users and then the next function will fetch orders.

Also an advice to keep objectId as the attribute for maintaining relationship instead of first_name (which I suppose is not a unique attribute).

Please find the example code structure below for waterfall:

```
async.waterfall({
    function(callback){
        var finalResponse = {}
        //FIND CATEGORIES TYPE ONE HERE
        .
        .
        .
        finalResponse.categoriesOne = categoriesFoundFromDb
        callback(null, finalResponse)

    },
    function(finalResponse, callback){
        //FIND CATEGORIES TYPE TWO HERE
        .
        .
        .
        finalResponse.categoriesTwo = categoriesFoundFromDb
        callback(null, finalResponse)
    },
    function(finalResponse, callback){
        //FIND USERS HERE
        .
        .
        .
        finalResponse.users = usersFoundFromDb
        callback(null, finalResponse)
    },
    function(finalResponse, callback){
        //FIND ORDERS HERE BASED ON USERS 
        var users = finalResponse.users
        .
        .
        .
        finalResponse.orders = ordersFoundFromDb
        callback(null, finalResponse)
    }, function(err, finalResponse) {
        var categoriesOne = finalResponse.categoriesOne
        var categoriesTwo = finalResponse.categoriesTwo
        var users = finalResponse.users
        var orders = finalResponse.orders
    });
});
```

Comment: than q 
can u help me how to write code for the above code by using async series